# how to parse sql and ubuntu logs

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse following logs in python which are in json object format. Can anyone suggest me how to do it in python?

## mysqllog:

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
```

## ubuntu log:

```
2018-10-12T04:25:39.841627Z        5 Init DB    mysql
```

Comment: what is the input format and expected output format?

Comment: #input is in json:             mysqlmessage = {
    "meta": {
        "clientID": 1234,
        },
    "logType": "<SYS/MYSQL/APACHE>",
    "logDetails": [
                    '2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages',
        ]
}

Comment: output:date: 2015-11-10
time: 15:26:56
code: 4348
description: [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with regex and log formats to parse logs, but it couldn't help me. Can you suggest me any solution, please?

Comment: What is the expected output for ubuntu logs?

Comment: Show me your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### MySQL logs

Take a look at the following regex:

`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s*(\d{4})\s*(.*)`

Whole explanation can be seen in the regex demo below, but basically what it does is it looks for:

- a date (1st pair of `()`)

  - first 4 digits (`\d{4}`) for a year, followed by `-`
  - two digits for month (`\d{2}`) followed by another dash
  - another two digits for day (`\d{2}`)
- a set of 0 or more spaces
- time (second pair of `()`, same logic as with date, just separated with colons (`:`)
- a set of 0 or more spaces
- another 4 digits (`\d{4}`) for code (if it can have any different number you can either skip curly braces and add a `+` instead, for a `\d+` - this will ask for one or more digits)
- a set of 0 or more spaces
- anything that is left out (so it will be a description)

[MySQL logs Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcqqqJ/1)

---

### Ubuntu logs

If I guessed the output of the Ubuntu logs correctly, it's more or less the same as MySQL logs, so I will not post full explanation - you can always check it on Regex101 demo below.

The Regex is as follows:
`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(?:\.\d+Z)\s*(\d+)\s*(.*)`

Some notes about it:

- main change is that it separates date and time differently, hence the `T` in this regex
- it also stores miliseconds (?) after seconds using `.#####` format - I **discard** this information in substitution (if you need it, let me know)
- the rest is basically the same

[Ubuntu logs Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcqqqJ/2)

Here is an updated Ubuntu demo that stores miliseconds as well and doesn't treat the `5` as code but a part of description: [Link to demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcqqqJ/3)

Comment: Thank you for solution. It worked for me. Can you please send the solution for Ubuntu logs also?

Comment: Provide the example output for ubuntu logs and I will update the answer

Comment: input:  2018-10-12T04:25:39.841627Z  5 Init DB  mysql     output: date:2018-10-12 time:  04:25:39 841627Z  description:   5 Init DB  mysql

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if the format is OK. Oh, and I thought this `5` in this line is a code as in MySQL logs

Comment: Can you please tell me how to parse milliseconds also?

Comment: @Payal Edited again, take a look